# response.BinaryWrite problems (Text file contains PDF encoding)

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

So I have something very strange happening in my Asp.Net Website.

I have 2 seperate pages with the same code to download files stored in a SQL database.

One page is an admin version of the page where you can delete and upload files and also see the files ID.

The user end version of this page only displays the download button and the filename. The ID is hidden and used as a DataKey in the grid to select the file from the database.

Both pages work perfectly in development. But when I switched to our production staging server the user end version of the page will turn a simple one line text file into a bunch of gargly-goop PDF encoding when saving and opening it, while the admin version of the page still functions properly. PDF's download and view normal and word documents do the same thing that the text files do.

**Here is the code behind for the admin download section:**

```
protected void btnSaveAttachment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow selectedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string AttachmentID = "";
        string AttachmentName = "";
        if (selectedRow.Cells[1].Text != null && selectedRow.Cells[2].Text != null)
        {
            AttachmentID = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            AttachmentName = selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        }

        byte[] objData = Utility.SaveAttachmentBytes(AttachmentID);

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", " no-store, no-cache ");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + AttachmentName + ";");
        response.BinaryWrite(objData);
        response.Flush();

        if (response != null)
        {
            response.End();
        }

    }
```

**Here is the code behind for the user download section:**

```
protected void btnSaveAttachment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow selectedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        //string AttachmentID = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        string AttachmentID = grdAttachments.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();
        string AttachmentName = "";
        if (selectedRow.Cells[1].Text != null)
        {
            AttachmentName = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        }

        byte[] objData = Utility.SaveAttachmentBytes(AttachmentID);

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", " no-store, no-cache ");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + AttachmentName + ";");
        response.BinaryWrite(objData);
        response.Flush();

        //File.Delete(SavePath);

        if (response != null)
        {
            response.End();
        }
    }
```

I am at a point where I just dont know what the heck is going on. The only other difference in the pages front end code is the user page load some text from the database into a label and has a telerik textbox control. (I have tried stripping out all other items on the page but still files other than PDF try to encode as a PDF.)

**Here is what a 1 line text file looks like when saving and opening it.**

````
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
9 0 obj<</H[516 160]/Linearized 1/E 5419/L 14363/N 2/O 12/T 14137>>
endobj

xref
9 11
0000000016 00000 n
0000000676 00000 n
0000000516 00000 n
0000000753 00000 n
0000000881 00000 n
0000000976 00000 n
0000001511 00000 n
0000001903 00000 n
0000002142 00000 n
0000002387 00000 n
0000002463 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 20/Prev 14127/Root 10 0 R/Info 8 0 R/ID[<3d8f2faf909b30f75011a461bd4aff97><b62071c85b58ab4d8f0b23af1811506f>]>>
startxref
0
%%EOF

11 0 obj<</Length 82/Filter/FlateDecode/L 90/S 53>>stream
xÚb```f``
‘BVœÀ   cf`aàXÀàÎ°…Ql
HT  ÈAPÌÀàÃÀÃì ,³Ñ†Ë`%·Hˆ…Aý!fb€  O{Ì
endstream
endobj
10 0 obj<</Pages 6 0 R/Type/Catalog/PageLabels 4 0 R/Metadata 7 0 R>>
endobj
12 0 obj<</Contents 19 0 R/Type/Page/Parent 6 0 R/Rotate 0/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/CropBox[0 0 612 792]/Resources 13 0 R>>
endobj
13 0 obj<</Font<</TT2 14 0 R/TT4 15 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]/ExtGState<</GS1 18 0 R>>>>
endobj
14 0 obj<</Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/BaseFont/TimesNewRomanPSMT/FirstChar 32/LastChar 150/Subtype/TrueType/FontDescriptor 16 0 R/Widths[250 0 0 0 0 833 778 0 333 333 0 564 250 333 250 278 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 278 0 0 0 0 0 0 722 667 667 722 611 556 722 0 333 389 0 611 889 722 722 556 722 667 556 611 722 722 944 722 722 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 444 500 444 500 444 333 500 500 278 278 500 278 778 500 500 500 500 333 389 278 500 500 722 500 500 444 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 500]>>
endobj
15 0 obj<</Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/BaseFont/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT/FirstChar 32/LastChar 121/Subtype/TrueType/FontDescriptor 17 0 R/Widths[250 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 250 0 500 500 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 722 722 0 0 0 0 389 0 0 0 0 0 778 0 0 0 556 667 722 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 500 0 444 0 444 333 500 0 278 0 0 0 833 556 0 0 0 444 389 333 556 500 722 0 500]>>
endobj
16 0 obj<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontBBox[-568 -307 2028 1007]/FontName/TimesNewRomanPSMT/Flags 34/StemV 82/CapHeight 656/XHeight 0/Ascent 891/Descent -216/ItalicAngle 0/FontFamily(Times New Roman)/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400>>
endobj
17 0 obj<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontBBox[-558 -307 2034 1026]/FontName/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT/Flags 34/StemV 136/CapHeight 656/XHeight 0/Ascent 891/Descent -216/ItalicAngle 0/FontFamily(Times New Roman)/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 700>>
endobj
18 0 obj<</Type/ExtGState/SA false/OP false/SM 0.02/op false/OPM 1>>
endobj

etc....................

endstream
endobj
4 0 obj<</Nums[0 5 0 R]>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</S/D>>
endobj
6 0 obj<</Count 2/Kids[12 0 R 1 0 R]/Type/Pages>>
endobj
7 0 obj<</Length 3339/Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML>>stream
<?xpacket begin='ï»¿' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<?adobe-xap-filters esc="CRLF"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/' x:xmptk='XMP toolkit 2.9.1-13, framework 1.6'>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' xmlns:iX='http://ns.adobe.com/iX/1.0/'>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:d5ef0fdf-fd89-4be0-a57d-fcab92aa8d2b' xmlns:pdf='http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/' pdf:Producer='Acrobat Distiller 6.0 (Windows)'></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:d5ef0fdf-fd89-4be0-a57d-fcab92aa8d2b' xmlns:xap='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/' xap:CreatorTool='PScript5.dll Version 5.2' xap:ModifyDate='2005-06-10T14:07:36-04:00' xap:CreateDate='2005-06-10T14:07:36-04:00'></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:d5ef0fdf-fd89-4be0-a57d-fcab92aa8d2b' xmlns:xapMM='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/' xapMM:DocumentID='uuid:2aee5402-c607-44cd-a815-8ad3a0bf0a56'/>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:d5ef0fdf-fd89-4be0-a57d-fcab92aa8d2b' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' dc:format='application/pdf'><dc:title><rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang='x-default'>Microsoft Word - 1 - DTOD Overview.doc</rdf:li></rdf:Alt></dc:title><dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>AttardA</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator></rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                 
<?xpacket end='w'?>
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj<</ModDate(D:20050610140736-04'00')/CreationDate(D:20050610140736-04'00')/Title(Microsoft Word - 1 - DTOD Overview.doc)/Creator(PScript5.dll Version 5.2)/Producer(Acrobat Distiller 6.0 \(Windows\))/Author(AttardA)>>
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000005419 00000 n
0000005544 00000 n
0000005638 00000 n
0000010369 00000 n
0000010402 00000 n
0000010425 00000 n
0000010482 00000 n
0000013897 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 9>>
startxref
116
%%EOF
````

**RESOLVED**

The issue was the DataKeys[0] was always selecting the 0 item in the array of keys. I changed that to:

```
string AttachmentID = grdAttachments.DataKeys[selectedRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

And now all is working fine! Wish I would have debugged closer into the attachmentID!

It just so happened that there was 2 documents that were the same and I though I was downloading the correct document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your admin section:

```
string AttachmentID = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

In your user section:

```
string AttachmentID = grdAttachments.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString();
```

I would have to assume that the user section assignment is not doing what you expect it to, since the logic isn't the same for both. Verify what AttachmentID is set to in each case, perhaps via logging.

Comment: I to Thought this was going to be the issue at first. But the propper attachment downloads and views fine in development using this very code and I have stepped through the code to insure the DataKey is the proper attachment ID.

Comment: The difference must them be environmental. Consider the database and table schema (maybe do a diff/compare of them), or the Telerik version.

Comment: On second thought I am going to re-evaluate the attachmentID.

Comment: DataKeys[0] is selecting the 0 item in the array of datakeys. It just so happened that there was 2 documents that were the same and I though I was downloading the correct document.

Now I need to select DataKey[i] i being the number of the Row i have selected.